# Ordering operations in ReactiveCocoa with concurrent delegate callbacks

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I am still trying to wrap my head around ReactiveCocoa, and one thing in particular is causing headaches. I would like to have a declarative interface to the CoreBluetooth API that lets me do something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *registerValue;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *serialNumber;

RACSignal *characteristics = [[RACObserve(self, connectedPeripheral) flattenMap:^RACStream *(CBPeripheral *peripheral) {
    return [peripheral rac_discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kBLEServiceUUIDString]]];
}] flattenMap:^RACStream *(CBService *service) {
    return [service rac_discoverCharacteristics:nil];
}];

RACSignal *devInfoCharacteristics = [[RACObserve(self, connectedPeripheral) flattenMap:^RACStream *(CBPeripheral *peripheral) {
    return [peripheral rac_discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kDevInfoServiceUUIDString]]];
}] flattenMap:^RACStream *(CBService *service) {
    return [service rac_discoverCharacteristics:nil];
}];

RACSignal *registerUpdates = [[[characteristics filter:^BOOL(CBCharacteristic *characteristic) {
    return ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kRegisterCharacteristicUUIDString]]);
}] flattenMap:^RACStream *(CBCharacteristic *characteristic) {
    return [[characteristic rac_updateNotificationState:YES] mapReplace:characteristic];
}] flattenMap:^RACStream *(CBCharacteristic *characteristic) {
    return [characteristic rac_didUpdateValue];
}];

RACSignal *serialNumberSignal = [[[characteristics filter:^BOOL(CBCharacteristic *characteristic) {
    return ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kSerialNumberCharacteristicUUIDString]]);
}] flattenMap:^RACStream *(CBCharacteristic *characteristic) {
    return [characteristic rac_didUpdateValue];
}];

RAC(self, serialNumber) = serialNumberSignal;
RAC(self, registerValue) = registerUpdates;
```

Now, the implementation of rac_discoverServices looks something like this (a category on CBPeripheral):

```
- (RACSignal *)rac_discoverServices:(NSArray *)serviceUUIDs
{
    @weakify(self);
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        @strongify(self);
        RACDisposable *disposable = [[[[self rac_didDiscoverServices] take:1] flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
            return [[[self.services rac_sequence] signal] filter:^BOOL(CBService *service) {
                if (!serviceUUIDs) {
                    return YES;
                } else {
                    for (CBUUID *uuid in serviceUUIDs) {
                        if ([uuid isEqual:service.UUID]) {
                            return YES;
                        }
                    }
                    return NO;
                }
            }];
        }] subscribe:subscriber];
        [self discoverServices:serviceUUIDs];
        return disposable;
    }];
}
```

The problem is that I don't *think* this can work, because I don't believe the callback ordering can be guaranteed. So what I really want is to be able to ensure that the subscription to the second signal cannot issue the call to discover new services until the first signal has completed.

I understand that RACCommand will prevent concurrent operation, but I don't see a way to use it to ensure that the operations are queued.

Is there some obvious solution I am missing? The only thing I can think of is to somehow maintain a queue of calls and call discover again when the prior signal is disposed of (and I'm not certain that would work either).

Comment: @erikprice, thanks. I wrote this in haste, and I did indeed mean subscription. I believe that my problem was not that the callbacks were re-ordered, but that I did not receive the values on the main thread scheduler (the CoreBluetooth central is using a dedicated queue). However, I'd still be interested to know if there's an idiomatic way to accomplish what I described.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for, but you can serialize subscriptions to multiple signals (ensuring each completes before subscribing to the next) using `+ [RACSignal concat]`.

Comment: @erikprice, thanks again. I see that `concat` would give serializability, but I'm not sure how I would necessarily use it with the above example. In this specific case, I'd like to have two separate signals generated from discovering the two services and associated characteristics. I'm probably being overly pedantic, as I could just have one and filter by UUID, but it starts to get rather long and ugly, and feels less declarative to me.

Comment: I know you're aware of the difference between them, but I think you're conflating signals and subscriptions. You can't "order" two signals. A signal is really nothing more than a function. Without a caller (or subscriber, in this case), it's just inert functionality waiting to happen. You can't say "Signal B should always wait for Signal A", because without a subscriber, Signal A doesn't really "exist" as far as timing/sequencing is concerned. What you can sequence are the *subscriptions* to those signals.

Comment: @erikprice, bear with me for one more comment. I omitted an important piece, which is the use of the RAC macro to assign the signal values to two properties on the object (edited above). The serial number is not the best example - it is essentially read only once, but there is a BLE register which changes frequently, and delivers notifications (and I'll have more registers shortly). Now, the `rac_didUpdateValue` signals can produce interleaved values in time without an issue, but the two subscriptions on `rac_discoverServices` are concurrent. Can I sequence the earlier part of the pipeline?

Comment: I know I'm beating this to death. It's very helpful for me trying to understand RC, though. I could `concat` the two signals to produce a signal of services, and then split that into two dependent signals that filter based on the UUID, then feed those to the respective characteristic discovery signals, and finally bind to the properties with the RAC macro. Apologies if my terminology has been imprecise. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If you do that, bear in mind that you will be creating two separate subscriptions, which may result in two separate calls to the services. Cold signals make it easier to reason about the behavior of subscribers, but the tradeoff is that each subscriber gets its own "copy" of the work.

Comment: Right, that is the source of my original confusion. If I do the `concat` and create dependent signals that are then subscribed to, I can control the order of calls to the CoreBluetooth API (discover1 -> discover_callback1 -> discover2 -> discover_callback2). With the original code snippet, I cannot guarantee this. To be more precise, I want to prevent (discover1 -> discover 2 -> discover_callback2 -> discover_callback1). Anyway, I think I'll go with the `concat` and call it a day.